# Let no-one push to branch on Github without review

Tags: github

Is there a way to protect a branch from being pushed to without having the review functionality on?

### Desired workflow:

Block the branches `dev` or `master` from being able to make commits to it directly. Only allow merge requests to go through.

---

Currently, the only way I can figure out the ability to block pushes to a branch is one of two ways:

**Review Functionality**: This is not ideal because it doesn't let me be the **1** reviewer and there is no one else working on this branch but me.

[image]

**Restricting who can push**: This won't work because then I am not allowed to merge into the branch either.

[image]

Comment: Push <> merge? Without push rights you should merge it? A

Comment: @Julian I don't want to be able to make direct commits to master/dev. I want to branch off, and eventually merge my new branch into dev.

Comment: Then just *do that*. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thats not my question. I want to RESTRICT it. I want to be able to enforce the rule like you can do on bitbucket, gitlab, etc. The problem I want to solve is if you try to make a direct commit to master/dev, it says permission denied.

Comment: are you the administrator of the project?

Comment: That's *not* a problem. What's the second half of that sentence, starting with "because"?

Comment: I'm not "picking a fight", I'm *asking for context*. Are people not following the process? Is that causing actual problems?

Comment: @jonrsharpe "because" i don't want anyone to mistakingly commit to dev/master because this pushes directly to production or a staging and it's important to merge first. But I don't feel the need to need to "review" right now I just want the extra step of merging first.

Comment: Then the actual problem seems to be that you don't have any kind of validation between a commit and production. If you're not reviewing anyway, what's the point of a stage where you could? Just having to merge doesn't actually mean your code will work afterwards. Actual solutions look like CI/CD, where automated tests verify your commit and only push working updates to production.

Comment: Last I checked this could only be possible 9n GitHub Enterprise or client-side git commit hooks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're the administrator of the project, you can still use "Require pull request reviews before merging",

[image]

because as administrator you could by-pass that rule if you don't enable:

[image]

In the PR you could by-pass the review and still merge it (just tested it):

[image]

Comment: This will not be for an administrator account but I appreciate the answer.

Comment: If nobody else could review, how aren't you the admin ;)